# Trigger for count number of deletes

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-delete

I have this table called books

```
create table books (price INT,title VARCHAR(50),type VARCHAR(5));
```

And I need a trigger that inserts in another table called `myregister` the current date, and the number of books deleted in that date. So I came up with this:

```
    CREATE TABLE myregister (dates DATE,number INT);

    DELIMITER |
    CREATE TRIGGER deleted AFTER DELETE on books
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    set @cnt = if(@cnt is null, 1, (@cnt+1));
    set @dat = CURDATE();
    INSERT INTO myregister values(CURDATE(),@cnt);
    END;
    |
    DELIMITER ;
```

but there are 2 problems:

1. The variable is global, and it counts for every book deleted, it doesn't matter the date.
2. The trigger counts for every row, so at the end, the table myregister has `n` rows, each one for every book deleted.

Answer (score 1):

If you redefine the `myregister` table so that the `dates` column is unique, you could rewrite the trigger to insert a row **if one does not already exist**, or increment the counter if it does.

Caution: `number` is a reserved word in MySQL. Your trigger could have a more-specific name since `deleted` won't be obvious if you add more triggers for other tables.

```
CREATE TABLE myregister (dates DATE PRIMARY KEY, `number` INT);

CREATE TRIGGER deleted AFTER DELETE on books
FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO myregister VALUES(CURDATE(), 1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `number` = `number` + 1;

INSERT INTO books VALUES(1, 'test', 'test'), (2, 'test', 'test'),
   (3, 'test', 'test'), (4, 'test', 'test'), (5, 'test', 'test');

DELETE FROM books;

INSERT INTO books VALUES(1, 'test', 'test'), (2, 'test', 'test'),
   (3, 'test', 'test'), (4, 'test', 'test'), (5, 'test', 'test');

DELETE FROM books;

SELECT * FROM myregister;

-- 2016-05-09,  10
```

Comment: You can use [14.2.5.3 INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: @wchiquito Yes, that would be preferable. Will edit.

Comment: @MattRaines Thank you very much, it really helped me.

Comment: @viversba Hi, if his solution worked for you, you can accept his answer. See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for how to do it.